# Firebase realtime database. Is there way to set timestamp of record creation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set timestamp of record creation in database

For example: I POST (via Firebase Realtime Database REST API) object

```
{"name": "Name", "last_name": "LastName" }
```

And then I can see in console:

```
{"name": "Name", "last_name": "LastName", "time_stamp": 1563371542446 }
```

Comment: [Firebase server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)

Comment: André Kool could you explain your comment?

Comment: Just like the name and last name you can include timestamp in your post and using the server value firebase will populate it with the server timestamp at the time it's added to the database

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I perform POST via REST API.
I have no instance of Database.

Comment: You might want to take some time and read the documentation: [server value in rest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values)

Comment: André Kool Well, thanks for direction

Solution is to POST json like this:

{  
   "server_timestamp":{  
      ".sv":"timestamp"
   },
   "name":"LAURA.PALMER",
   "email":"LAURA@gmail.com"
}

And record appears in console:
{  
   "server_timestamp":1563376669445,
   "name":"LAURA",
   "email":"LAURA@gmail.com"
}

Answer (score 6):

Solution is to POST json like this:

```
{  
   "server_timestamp":{  
      ".sv":"timestamp"
   },
   "name":"Name",
   "email":"Name@gmail.com"
}
```

And record appears in console:

```
{  
   "server_timestamp":1563376669445,
   "name":"Name",
   "email":"Name@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is for this

[Clock Skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew)

> While Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is much more accurate, and
>   preferable for most read/write ops, it can occasionally be useful to
>   estimate the clients clock skew with respect to Firebase's servers. We
>   can attach a callback to the location /.info/serverTimeOffset to
>   obtain the value, in milliseconds, that Firebase clients will add to
>   the local reported time (epoch time in milliseconds) to estimate the
>   server time. Note that this offset's accuracy can be affected by
>   networking latency, and so is useful primarily for discovering large
>   (> 1 second) discrepancies in clock time.

And you can implement it with the followin way

```
var offsetRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
});
```

Comment: I have no ref to Firebase package.
Let's see at this question like "Can you post via Postman/whatever object so firebase could set timestamp value?"

Comment: If you dont use Firebase Database , I dont think possible getting the server time by any chance, if there is no documentation about it for the REST API, this and what André commented is the only way I see it possible. But hey, this is just my opinion, there is Firebase proffesionals here that can help you better with the issue

Comment: Gastón Saillén solution found

Comment: Excelent @Aleksandr , you can share it below in an answer, so others can look at the question and get help too :)